# ¿Cómo aumentar el valor de un número en una lista?

Tags: python

Ejemplo: El folio inicia en 1150

```py
folio=[1150]
```

Y en el momento que haya un registro nuevo cambie a

```py
folio=[1151]
```

Y así sucesivamente

Comment: Cierto! Y en el casó de listas cómo se podría hacer?

Comment: @CandidMoe eso era antes que edites la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices

```
folio=[1150]
```

estás creando una lista con un sólo elemento, el valor 1150. Eso es completamente innecesario; basta con

```
folio=1150
```

Luego, más tarde, cuando aparezca otro documento y necesites generar el siguiente folio, basta con:

```
folio += 1
```

instrucción que le suma 1 al folio.

#### Demo

Este código pide líneas de texto, les asigna un número de folio y las imprime. Termina al recibir una línea vacía:

```
folio = 0

while True:
    doc = input("documento? ").strip()
    if doc:
        folio += 1
        print(f"Documento N°{folio} = {doc}")
    else:
        break
```

produce

```
documento? Formulario 21
Documento N°1 = Formulario 21
documento? Papeleta deposito
Documento N°2 = Papeleta deposito
documento? 

Process finished with exit code 0
```